# Is it ok to convert Immutable.js Map to Object inside of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using redux and Immutable.js in my application, I added Immutable to the app a few weeks after I started developing the project and as I didn't want to change my current components to the Immutable's .get() syntax I converted the Immutable Maps in my store to Objects before using them inside of my components. Ex.:

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    login: store.login.toObject(),
    user: store.user.toObject()
  };
})
```

Is it a bad practice?Would that be relevant for the performance of my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a VERY bad practice. In order for Immutable to convert your Immutable maps to JavaScript it has to walk the entire object; this is going to be slow.  Also, you are losing a huge amount of the actual value of using ImmutableJS with React and Redux. Specifically, you now can no longer short circuit needless re-renders with a simple implementation of [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

Comment: Could you elaborate upon what that short-circuiting technique would look like with `shouldComponentUpdate`? Also, would there be a way to do this with the function-based React components instead of the class-based ones?

Comment: @NicholasMontaño You will need to use ES6 classes if you want the lifecycle hooks. As it stands, `react-redux` implements a shallow comparison automatically that you get for free when wrapping your component in `connect`, so unless you want to do something more custom, it's fine that you're using the functional component.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use ImmutableJS `Maps`, but don't want to have to use `get` syntax, you can use [`Records`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record). They have all the functionality of `Maps`, except for arbitrary-value keys (which accessor syntax wouldn't work on anyways).

A brief example:

```
// Specify the allowed fields and their default values
const TodoListState = Immutable.Record({ todos: undefined, filter: undefined })

// Instantiate the record using `new` and an object with the desired KV mapping
const initialTodoState = new TodoListState({ 
  todos: Immutable.List(),
  filter: undefined, // this is already the default, but I prefer being explicit
})

const initialTodos = initialTodoState.todos // List()
```